# Jquery event won't fire when element is displayed via mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I have some content that is fed in from mysql that, when clicked should fire an alert()...
however, this is not working...

here is my code for the code that is fed in from php/get_answers.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/include_all.php"); ?>
<?php $answers = $question->get_answers_for_question($_GET['id']); ?>
<?php while($row = $answers->fetch_array()){ ?>
  <!-- ALL ANSWERS HERE -->
  <div class = 'answer-row'>
    <div class = 'answer-side'>
        <div class = 'arrow-contain-answer' type = 'answer' id = 'arrow-up' answer-id = '<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'></div>
        <div class = 'answer-votes-contain'>
            <?php echo $row['popularity']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class = 'arrow-contain-answer' id = 'arrow-down'answer-id = '<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'></div>
      </div>

    <div class = 'answer-content'>
      <?php 
        echo $row['content'];
      ?>
    </div>

    <div class = 'actions'>
        <a href = '#' class= 'add-comment' id = '<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'> add comment </a>
    </div>

  </div>

<?php } ?>
```

and here is the jquery on the page that it is displayed on:

```
$(".arrow-contain-answer").click(function(){
    alert();
});
```

What I want to happen is when someone clicks the element with the class of 'arrow-contain-answer' an event will occur..

I think I have had problems before when elements are being 'fed' into the page via mysql/php.

Comment: Do you really have spaces between the attributes and their values? That won't work.

Comment: nope, when i copied and pasted my formatting got all funky... i tried to clean it up as much as possible

Comment: Don't surround the equals sign `=` with spaces when defining html attributes. Also, use double quotes for such attributes: `class="arrow-contain-answer"` instead of `class = 'arrow-contain-answer'`

Comment: Where are you including your jQuery code? If it's before this HTML section, you can wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { // your code });`. If it's before, then you are trying to bind to elements that don't exist on the page yet. The ready() function will run after the DOM has been completely loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".arrow-contain-answer", function(){
    alert();
});
```

Try this way for dynamic added elements!

Comment: oh and can you tell me why i need to add $(document) ?

Comment: $("element_selector") works only if your element is at the html code on page load, if its added after page is loaded this is the correct way to write your code.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

even better(performancewise) if you delegate it with the closest static element(parent) which is present in the document when dynamic fed element is added.

```
$('.answer-row').on("click", ".arrow-contain-answer", function(){
  alert('clicked');
});
```

to read more about [on delegated](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) event